# How to trigger scene custom behaviour in Xcode 15

Tags: arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I'm working on an AR App. With Reality Composer and Xcode 14 I was triggering custom behaviours from with just:

`myScene.notifications.myBox.post()` 
called from

`let myScene = try! Experience.loadBox()`

Now in Xcode 15 I don't have an Experience instead with the .reality file I have to use Entities so now I've tried to call:

`let objectAR = try! Entity.load(named: "myProject.reality")`

But at this point I can't access the "Scene"

How can I trigger my previously Reality Composer exported custom behaviour from that ?

Comment: Read the following post – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748779/can-we-use-reality-composer-pro-for-arview/77512647#77512647

Comment: @AndyJazz Thank you, now I have a better understanding of how it works.