# Can't find/implement a Experience.rcproject (Reality Composer) in my RealityKit project

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I need to create a .rcproject file to implement 3D models for my application.

When I create a file with the Augmented Reality template in Xcode, it was supposed to have 3 files:
`AppDelegate.swift`;
`ContentView.swift`;
`Experience.rcproject`.

However, the last one is not there, and I can't find it in the "New File" session.
Do I need to install something else? What am I doing wrong?

I already tried updating my Mac to the latest version, downloading the Reality Composer app and searching a lot, but none of this worked.

Answer (score 2):

#### Xcode 15 vs Xcode 14

The latest version of Xcode (v.15) comes with a new prototyping tool called [Reality Composer Pro 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reality-composer-pro/info), which is not interchangeable with the previous [Reality Composer 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reality-composer/info) developer app included in Xcode 14. Both versions of Xcode [are capable of working with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748779/can-we-use-reality-composer-pro-for-arview/77512647#77512647) the great old Reality Composer 1.5 app. However, to be able to automatically load the `Experience.rcproject` file into a RealityKit project, use Xcode 14. When working with non-pro Reality Composer's scenes in Xcode 15, `.rcproject` files must be imported manually.

Comment: Thank you!
I'm still having trouble to create this file tho.
How do I import it manually?

Comment: Prototype a scene in macOS Reality Composer 1.5, save it as `.rcproject` file, then drag-and-drop it to Xcode 15's Navigator Area.