# Reality Composer Pro - Animation

Tags: realitykit, visionos, reality-composer-pro

I hope this message finds an apple developer,

I am currently working on a project using Reality Composer Pro on its desktop version. My primary challenge involves initiating a custom animation for a primitive shape or entity within the application. On the iPad version of Reality Composer, I am familiar with the use of a "behaviour panel" to achieve this. However, I am at a loss on how to locate or access a similar feature in the desktop version.

Could somebody kindly provide guidance or instructions on how to use this feature on the desktop platform? Any assistance would be invaluable to me, especially as I am developing for the new `visionOS` platform using Xcode 15.2 where very few documentation is available.

I tried reading the full documentation on the Apple website. I tried asking the few Youtubers that started using the new platform. I tried contacting Apple dev department. I tried to look and search for it myself on the desktop UI. Now I am trying here.

Comment: Read the last paragraph in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748779/can-we-use-reality-composer-pro-for-arview/77512647#77512647).