# How to set low gravity in RealityKit

Tags: realitykit

Is it possible in RealityKit to have low gravity for models so they fall to the surface slowly. I have the following code but in this code the gravity is 9.8 m/s2 (default). What can I do to change the gravity so objects falls slowly?

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
    
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

    // Create a cube model
    let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.1, cornerRadius: 0.005)
    let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .gray, roughness: 2.0, isMetallic: true)
    let box = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
    box.transform.translation.y = 0.05
    box.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
    box.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default, material: .default, mode: .dynamic)
    

    // Create horizontal plane anchor for the content
    let anchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: .any , minimumBounds: SIMD2<Float>(0.2, 0.2)))
    
    anchor.addChild(box)
    
    // Add the horizontal plane anchor to the scene
    arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)

    return arView
    
}
```

PS: I know I can apply a linear impulse but I was just wondering if there is another way.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75994868/how-to-spawn-an-entity-in-zero-gravity-with-realitykit) gives you two ways to control a gravity.