# How to use gesture modifiers in RealityKit when removing children from parent entity without removing the entire scene

Tags: swiftui, arkit, uipangesturerecognizer, realitykit, reality-composer

So I have been struggling with a complex ( 10+ children ) scene that I created in Reality Composer and tested but REALLY struggled when bringing it to Reality Kit.

What I want to do is, after the scene is imported, and all the actions on each model are implemented, I want to be able to drag the all the models at once ( so far so good, thus far I was able to do )

AND

**and once the dragging ends, I want it to return to the initial state, where I can click on each entity separately and each animation plays.**

**BUT
This is the part that doesn't work. What frustrates me is, I was able to do all of this so easily using Reality Composer, and it worked so well when I tested it... but when I bring this into realitykit... IT'S A MESS!!!**

What complicates the issue is, in order to drag all the elements at once, I had to create a separate parent entity which groups all the children. This works to drag the entire group, but I when I want to turn back to the initial situation, it doesn't work. If I try to remove the group entity, the entire scene disappears.

I did this hacky version where the model starts as non-dragging and after activating the animations, it turns into a draggable model. But this is sadly a partial solution. It doesn't let me go back.

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {

    
        
        ExperienceFullB.loadBoxAsync(completion: { result in
            do {
                let boxScene = try result.get()
                arView.scene.anchors.append(boxScene)
                
            
     
                    
                
                
                boxScene.actions.behavior.onAction = handleTapOnEntity(_:)
                func handleTapOnEntity(_ entity: Entity?) {
                    guard let entity = entity else { return }
                    //redModel.setParent(cubesAnchor)
                    print("hello")
                    
                    let redModel =  boxScene.children[0].children[0]
                    let group = ModelEntity() as ModelEntity & HasCollision
                    
                   // boxScene.addChild(redModelPhysics)
                    group.addChild(redModel)
                    group.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
                    
                    self.arView.installGestures(.all, for: group)
                    
                    let shape = ShapeResource.generateBox(width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1)
                    let collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [shape],
                                                       mode: .trigger,
                                                       filter: .sensor)
                    group.components.set(collision)
                    
                    
                    let anchor = AnchorEntity()
                    anchor.addChild(group)
                    anchor.scale = [5,5,5]
                    arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
                    //print(cubesAnchor)
                    print(boxScene)
                }
                
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
    
    
        
      

        
   
        
        
        return arView
    }
```

**These are the rabbit holes I went through**

**Drag Gesture Recognizer with SwiftUI  - not applicable...**
Plus I am very confused about the dragging gesture. I have come across multiple examples of swiftui using UIView but I don't think this works on ARKit/RealityKit.
[image]

**pan gesture recognizer from UIKit doesn't work either**
I found [an example using UIKit from an Apple sample code,](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/controlling_entity_collisions_in_realitykit) where the entity is created from code ( not imported from Reality Composer ), and it's only ONE element that you can drag and it changes by using the hasPhysics mode, from static to kinetic and so forth.  [Like this example answered by Andy Jazz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59183770/how-do-i-make-an-entity-a-physics-entity-in-realitykit)
Here's the part of the code I tried to adapt to use

```
// MARK: - Gestures -
    
    /// Sets up the pan gesture recognizer used to move entities
    fileprivate func setGestures() {
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panned(_:)))
        panGesture.delegate = self
        arView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
    
    /// Delegate method called by the pan gesture recognizer
    @objc
    func panned(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        switch sender.state {
            case .ended, .cancelled, .failed:
                // When a pan gesture ends for any reason, all entities will
                // return to being dynamic physics bodies
                movableEntities.flatMap { $0 }.forEach { $0.setPhysicsBodyMode(to: .dynamic) }
                
                // Have VoiceOver announce when dragging has ended.
                if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                    let announce = "Dragging ended."
                    UIAccessibility.post(notification: .announcement, argument: announce)
                }
            default:
                return
        }
    }
    
    /// Needed for the sample project’s custom pan gesture recognizer to work. RealityKit installs its own
    /// gesture recognizer (EntityGestureRecognizers.) behind the scenes. This project’s gesture recognizer
    /// needs to co-exist and run simultaneously with that one. Returning true allows them to both run together.

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                           shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        true
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        // Turn the gesture recognizer's associated entity into a kinematic
        //physics body, which allows the user to manipulate its position.
        guard let translationGesture = gestureRecognizer as? EntityTranslationGestureRecognizer,
            let entity = translationGesture.entity as? MovableEntity else { return true }
        entity.physicsBody?.mode = .static
```

**The complication is the parent entity, again**

that was added and I don't know how to remove it correctly. I have used

```
 redModel.setParent(parentTwo)
```

but if I create a new 'dad' the action-clickable gestures I created using Reality Composer don't return.
HEEEEELLLLPPPPPPPP!!!!

Comment: UPDATE: It does does work now. I am not sure why it didn't work yesterday. I removed a print("hello") it can't be it. HOWEVER. A threading issue emerges and crashes the app after I have dragged/pressed buttons/played animations only a couple of times. ( Compared to the Reality Composer experience which was fluid... I realize I will probably have to use Combine for this.